# Esttab: Append rtf files with page break?

Tags: append, stata, page-break

I use a loop to append each regression table for various dependent variables into one file:

```
global all_var var1 var2 var3

foreach var of global all_var {

capture noisily : eststo mod0: reg  `var' i.female
capture noisily : eststo mod1: reg  `var' i.female
capture noisily : eststo mod2: reg  `var' i.female

esttab mod0  mod1  mod2  using "file_name.rtf", append
}
```

However, in the final `rtf` file some tables are stretching over two pages which does not look good.

Is there any way to avoid that, e.g. introduce some sort of pagebreak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing rtfutil, you may use rtfappend. Suppose you want a page break between mod1 and mod2.

```
    esttab mod0 mod1 using "file_name.rtf", replace
    tempname handle
    rtfappend `handle' using "file_name.rtf", replace
    file write `handle' "\page" _n
    rtfclose `handle'
    esttab mod2 using "file_name.rtf", append
```

If you want a line break, just replace \page with \line.

Answer (score 1):

The *community-contributed* package `rtfutil` provides a solution:

```
net describe rtfutil, from(http://fmwww.bc.edu/RePEc/bocode/r)

TITLE
      'RTFUTIL': module to provide utilities for writing Rich Text Format (RTF) files

DESCRIPTION/AUTHOR(S)
      
        The rtfutil package is a suite of file handling utilities for
      producing Rich Text Format (RTF) files in Stata, possibly
      containing plots and tables. These RTF files can then be opened
      by Microsoft Word, and possibly by alternative free word
      processors. The plots can be included by inserting, as linked
      objects, graphics files that might be produced by the graph
      export command in Stata. The tables can be included by using the
      listtex command, downloadable from SSC, with the handle() option.
```

Exact syntax will depend on your specific use case for which you do not provide any example data.